# Mandrill Codigniter

Tags: codigniter, mandrill

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем дело.Подключил все как положено в файл `config` добавил

```
    $config['mandrill_api_key'] = 'api_key';
```

Далее в `libraries` закинул файл `Mandrill.php` и поставил автозагрузку в `autoLoad`. 
Далее в контроллере прописываю следующий код

```
 $msg = array(
                "html" => "The Message",
                "text" => null,
                "from_email" => "jenika1.sidorov@gmail.com",
                "from_name" => "John Doe",
                "subject" => "Acme",
                "to" => array(array("email" => "jenika.sidorov@gmail.com")),
                "track_opens" => true,
                "track_clicks" => true,
                "auto_text" => true
            );

  $this->mandrill->messages_send($msg);
```

И вылетает Эксепшн

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Mandrill_Exception

Message: -

Filename: C:\XAMPP\htdocs\pipeline\application\libraries\Mandrill.php

Line Number: 108
```

Comment: вы пробовали загружать на самом контроллере?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27471066/4953620

Comment: Да читал этот топик уже с ног до головы,ничего не выходит

Comment: Type: Mandrill_HttpError

Message: API call to messages/send failed: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Filename: C:\XAMPP\htdocs\pipeline\application\libraries\Mandrill.php

Line Number: 126

Backtrace:

Comment: тут проблема не в сертификате SSL ? может вы аудентификацию почты на зашишенном уровне делаете и код не может получить сертификат ??

Comment: Скорее всего,как решить эту проблему не подскажете?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27208/discussion-between-quaresma89-and-saidolim-djuraev).